# How to get the machine configuration filename in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am porting an application from .NET Framework to .NET Core (Standard).

Within the application, we have the following code

```
   public LogMessageListenerFromConfig()
        : this(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ConfigurationFile, LoggingSection.DefaultName)
    { }

    public LogMessageListenerFromConfig(string section)
        : this(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile, section)
    { }

    public LogMessageListenerFromConfig(string filename, string section)
    {
        // todo: set up a file watcher and refresh the listeners (etc.) when it changes.
        var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = filename };
        var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        _section = LoggingSection.Section(configuration, section);
        Refresh();
    }
```

This appears to be compatible with .NET Core apart from the following statement

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

There is no `SetupInformation` on an AppDomain anymore. Fair enough I read that it would cause issues etc. However, how else can I get the application configuration file name in a utility class?

Please be aware that this class will be used in both console and asp.net (core) applications.

Any help appreciated

Stephen

Comment: Assuming you're also moving to .NET Core's JSON configuration file approach, with associated `ConfigurationBuilder` and `IConfiguration`, it's probably best to inject `IConfiguration` into where you need it.

Comment: No we were aiming to stay with standard framework configuration at the moment, we are trying to do a very minimal code change to keep the initial refactor as small as possible.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't support the old-style ASP.NET configuration at all. If you're targeting .NET Framework, you might have access to some of that API, but it's not going to work.

Comment: ASP.NET Core requires configuration from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. If you want to use the .NET Framework’s `app.config`, then you will have to use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to load that configuration and the convert it into a suitable format for ASP.NET Core to consume it. There is no built-in support and that’s by design.

Answer (score 6):

Same problem if you are porting a library to .Net Standard. Solution is this;
install this nuget package system.configuration.configurationmanager then you can use:

```
 var conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
 var configFilePath = conf.FilePath;
```

Comment: This works great for exe applications (and .net core ones).  I need to also get the web.config path for .net472 web applications that use my .netstandard2.0 library.  How can I do that?